# Add git repo in Sagemaker notebook insatnce using Terraform

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating my Sagemaker notebook instance using terraform. I want to add my git repository with Sagemaker notebook instance at the time of instance creation.

Please help me if there is any solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using Amazon SageMaker!

SageMaker supports associating git repositories to Notebook Instance which gets added to Notebook Instance during Create/Start.

Please checkout our blog post of how to add git repository to your Notebook Instances [git repository integration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-now-support-git-integration-for-increased-persistence-collaboration-and-reproducibility/).

For more information please see our documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-git-repo.html).

Thanks,

Neelam

Answer (score 0):

To extend this thread

Instead of adding a repo at notebook instance creation time, I need to add an additional repo (a CodeCommit repo) to an existing instance. In order to do that, I used the following steps:

1. add the CodeCommit repo to the Sagemaker account
2. stop the notebook instance if it is running
3. Edit the instance to add the repo as an additional git repo
4. wait for the notebook instance to finish updating
5. start the instance

Then the new repo will show up next to the existing repos in the instance's UI

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be supported now :

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_code_repository